# Permission Issues with Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, maui

I'm using .NET MAUI to write a mobile app for Android and Apple and I'm using Plugin.BLE.  I'm using bluetooth to communicate with a device.  I can get everything working, but having some strange permission issues on Android.  It seems I need `Bluetooth Scan` permissions and `Bluetooth Connect` permissions for the app to work.  It also seems like in older versions of Android (less than 12) I need `Location` permissions.

So I've added request permissions for the 3 types, however, the app only asks for one at a time.  For example, the first time you run the app, it will ask for location permission.  Then when you try to scan for bluetooth the app crashes.  The second time you run it, it will ask for bluetooth permissions.  In Android 12 or greater, you need `Bluetooth Connect` so it will crash again and finally on the third run all the permission can be granted and the app works great.

What am I doing wrong?  I need it to ask for permissions for all that are required the first time, so the user doesn't have to close the app multiple times.  Also, do I need location permission for bluetooth to work?  It seems on Android 9 it wouldn't work without location permissions.

*My MainActivity.cs*

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    private const int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 100;
    private const int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_SCAN_PERMISSION = 101;
    private const int REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 102;
    private const int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT_PERMISSION = 103;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

        // Request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission at runtime
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation },
                REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        }

        //Request the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission at runtime
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation },
                REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        }

        // Request the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission at runtime
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.BluetoothScan) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.BluetoothScan },
                REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_SCAN_PERMISSION);
        }

        //Request the BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission at runtime
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.BluetoothConnect) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.BluetoothConnect },
                REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION)
        {
            if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {
                // ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission granted, you can now scan for Bluetooth devices
            }
            else
            {
                // ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission denied, you can't scan for Bluetooth devices
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION_PERMISSION)
        {
            if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {
                // ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission granted, you can now scan for Bluetooth devices in the background
            }
            else
            {
                // ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission denied, you can't scan for Bluetooth devices in the background
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_SCAN_PERMISSION)
        {
            if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {
                // BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission granted, you can now scan for Bluetooth devices
            }
            else
            {
                // BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission denied, you can't scan for Bluetooth devices
            }
        }
        
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_CONNECT_PERMISSION)
        {
            if (grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
            {
                // BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission granted, you can now scan for Bluetooth devices
            }
            else
            {
                // BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission denied, you can't scan for Bluetooth devices
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*My AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't ask for all the permissions at once, but I don't see any logic that makes sure ALL are granted. That is, you can avoid the crash, by setting a boolean if ANY of the permission checks fail. This should be a final check, just before attempting access to bluetooth. Or to say it another way: don't assume user grants the permissions when asked; double-check them all just before access bluetooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do. I don't start scanning until I've checked each permission

```
IAdapter adapter;

public BluetoothLeScan()
{
    adapter = CrossBleAdapter.Current;
}

public async Task StartScanAsync(){
    if (adapter.Status != AdapterStatus.PoweredOn)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("tip", "Please turn on Bluetooth", "ok");
        return;
    }
    if (!await CheckPermissionStatus())
    {
        return;
    }
    //this.adapter.Scan().Subscribe(async (scanResult) =>{});
}


...

static async ValueTask<bool> CheckPermissionStatus()
{

    if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Android)
    {
        return true;
    }
    PermissionStatus status;
    if (DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 12)
    {
        status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<MyBluetoothPermission>();
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<MyBluetoothPermission>())
            {
                bool needPermission = await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("needPermission ", "Requires permission to scan and connect to Bluetooth", "go", "cancel");
                if (needPermission == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<MyBluetoothPermission>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("needPermission", "The function is temporarily unavailable because the permission is not obtained", "ok");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>())
        {
            bool needPermission = await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("needPermission", "Bluetooth requires location information to work", "go", "cancel");
            if (needPermission == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("needPermission", "The function is temporarily unavailable because the permission is not obtained", "ok");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Permissions Class

```
using static Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Permissions;

namespace LdgElevator.Connection.BluetoothLE.Helper
{
    public class MyBluetoothPermission : BasePlatformPermission
    {
#if ANDROID
        public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions => new List<(string permission, bool isRuntime)>
        {
            ("android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN",true),
            ("android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT",true)
        }.ToArray();
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Adapter` in your code?  Is it a `IAdapter`?  My IAdapter doesn't seem to have a Status method.

Answer (score 1):

To improve on [@itldg answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76338292/5122089) you can change your `RequiredPermissions` property to only request BT properties it needs based on version:

```
public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] RequiredPermissions
{
    get
    {
        var permissions = Build.VERSION.SdkInt switch
        {
            >= BuildVersionCodes.S => new[] { Manifest.Permission.BluetoothConnect, Manifest.Permission.BluetoothScan },
            > BuildVersionCodes.P => new[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation },
            _ => new[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation }
        };

        return permissions.Select(permission => (permission, true)).ToArray();
    }
}
```